# PHP: Auth Redirect issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

The Website I am working on has some weird cache issues. When I click on Sign In the first time it goes to the login page but when I logout and try to click on Sign In it redirects back to the homepage. Also when I access the site from b4m.bid4med.com/myaccount it redirects me to Login Page, after login it takes me back to b4m.bid4med.com/myaccount which redirects back to login page which then realizes I am logged in so redirects me to homepage. This all works fine when I disable cache in browser. I have also put the php code

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
```

Sorry if I am not explaining it clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some troublesome cache problems with login sessions too. Adding this header solved it for me:

```
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

(could be anytime in the past i assume)